# Expressing $F(x,y,z)$ in terms of $F(x,\alpha(x))$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

I am trying to solve following problem

> Let $F : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be given by $F(x,y,z) = (x^3 + 2x+e^z -1, y+z-1)$, $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Show that there are an open interval $U$ containing $0$ and a differentiable function $\alpha : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $F(x,\alpha(x)) = (0,0)$, $x\in U$ and find the derivative $\alpha'(0)$.

I have no clue for finding such $\alpha$.

---

My First guess is find from derivatives, From chain rule

\begin{align}
&\frac{dF}{dx} = (3x^2+2,0) , \quad \frac{dF}{dy} =(0,1) , \quad \frac{dF}{dz} =(e^z, 1)
\end{align}

Maybe this is more appropriated.
Setting $F(x,y,z)=(0,0)$ and solving $y,z,x$
i.e., Solving $y+z-1=0$ and $x^3+2x+e^z-1=0$. First I have $y+z=1$. Suppose $\alpha(x)=(y,1-y)$ with $y=y(x)$.  Then what I need to solve $x^3+2x+e^{1-y}-1=0$ solving for $y$,  $y=1-\log(-x^3-2x+1)$

Is this approach ok? Is my $\alpha$ unique?

Comment: Your second approach is fine, but you need to show that your choice of $y=y(x)$ exists on an open interval which includes zero, and is differentiable at x=0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\alpha:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$:

We can write the components as follows:
$$ x\mapsto(\alpha_1(x),\alpha_2(x))$$

By the definition of $F$:

$$F(x,\alpha(x))=(x^3+2x+e^{\alpha_1(x)}-1,\alpha_1(x)+\alpha_2(x)-1)=(0,0)$$

$$\implies x^3+2x+e^{\alpha_1(x)}-1=0$$
$$\alpha_1(x)=-\ln (1-2x-x^3)$$
From this we deduce that $$\alpha_2(x)=1-\alpha_1(x)=1+\ln(1-2x-x^3)$$

Let's go from here to find the other information:

$\alpha_1(x) \text{ exists}\iff x^3+2x-1<0$

We see that $\alpha_1(0)=-1<0$, so there's a point $x$ where $\alpha_1(x),\alpha_2(x)$ and $\alpha(x)$ exist as well.

Now, let $h(x)=x^3-2x-1$.
We know that $h'(x)=3x^2-2<0$ so that $\alpha_1(x)$ exists at least for $x\in(-\sqrt\frac{2}{3},\sqrt\frac{2}{3})$ which contains zero.

Now, $$\alpha'(0)=(\alpha_1^{'}(0),\alpha_2^{'}(0))$$

By Calculus 1, we know that $$\alpha_1^{'}(x)=-1\cdot\bigg(\frac{-2x-3x^2}{1-2x-x^3}\bigg)=\frac{2x+3x^2}{1-2x-x^3}$$
$$\alpha_2^{'}(x)=-\alpha_1^{'}(x)=\frac{-2x-3x^2}{1-2x-x^3}$$

Showing that $\alpha'(0)=(0,0)$